# how to Update two Activities with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

i have two activities that i want to update with an incoming SMS message from a BroadcastReceiver.
i have two layouts like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

i do not know how to make a BroadcastReceiver so the two layouts would be updated with SMS.
can you help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete explanation and a Demo example for [How to Update the UI in an Android Activity Using Data from a Background Service](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/)

Comment: thank you for your quick answer but i saw this example and its good
but it has only one activity and the BroadcastReceiver is inside that activity, i would prefer an external BroadcastReceiver and two Activities that could be updated from it.

Comment: the problem i do not know how exactly to update two activities on the same time, that is my problem.

Comment: But why you want to update two activities at the same time, when only one will be visible at a time.

Comment: @Candyman instead of updating the activity you can update the persisted activity-state-data that is loaded when the activity resumes.

Answer (score 1):

+1 only one activity is visible at the same time, however if you want more than one activity to consume this broadcast, here is my suggestion.

> both activities must register to that broadcast event.
>   surely the active one will consume and react.

at this point add one more step

> store smt in SharedPreferences, e.g. isBroadcasted = true

then

> both activities onResume method must check for this value and reset to false after reacting

hope I could explain it clear enough, if not plz shout here so that I can try to attach sample code.

*...

[Social Coding @ AspiroTV](http://github.com/AspiroTV)*